# Firebase : Is there a way to copy a collection content to another collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have 4 resturant with the same menu , and i wanna duplicate the first resturant's menu with firebase
is there a way ? or i should do it manualy ?
[Here's my menu collection that i wanna duplicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9jix.png)

Comment: Unfortunately, firebase offers no feature for collection duplication at the moment. I recommend writing a script in your back-end (assuming you have one) which stores the document as posted in your screenshot in your collection, then loops a number of times, each time creating a new collection with this document inside it.

Comment: Can u please show me how ?

Comment: Sure! What are you building your app on? I assume you have some functioning back-end, is that assumption correct?

Comment: Yeah am working with ionic/angular

Comment: @MouadOucherif Is this going to be duplicated only once or will it be an ongoing thing? ie. if a document is added to one restaurant should it automatically be added to another or will this replication happen only once (or at least on non automatic bursts)?